# How do I properly handle these exceptions?

Tags: testing, junit, exception

In the following method, I need to handle if a null gets passed in but I am unsure how. How do I handle this so this method will pass a JUnit test?

```
     public Album(String name) {

     if(name==null){

        // what do I do here?
     }
     this.name = name;
     this.images = new ArrayList<Image>();


     }
```

And in this method, how do I handle if the index passed in is either negative or greater than the size of the array list it is getting from?

```
    public Image getImage(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > images.size()) {

          // how to handle here?

    }
        return images.get(index);

}
```

I've tried various things for both, but these methods keep failing their JUnit tests. Thank you for any input you can give me.

Comment: you mention you've tried 'various things', what are those things you tried?

Comment: I was throwing the exceptions, but one of my group members said I should handle it, and not throw it. And I tried setting the name and index to default values, but then they weren't passing my JUnit tests

Answer (score 0):

```
if(name==null){
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("name");
}
```

although personally I don't see anything wrong with throwing `NullPointerException` directly.

```
if (index < 0 || index > images.size()) {
  throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBounds(index);
}
```

But you know what? `images.get(index)` will throw it as well, so don't bother checking it first. Less code to read and test. In fact you already made a mistake. Your precondition will let `index` equal to `images.size()`. There should have been `index >= images.size()`.

Comment: I was throwing them, but one of my group members said I shouldn't be throwing it, I should be handling it.

Comment: @user1795374: sure, so how can you handle them? Use empty string instead of `null` name? Maybe. Take first (last?) element from the array if out of bounds? Unlikely... Whatever you do depends on your requirements. Your group member must be more specific.

Comment: For some reason, when I said,

        if(name==null){
                name="";
          }


My JUnit test did not pass

Comment: What does the unit test indicate should happen if you pass a null name?